# Convert a (xn;yn;zn) vector to a 3 (x,y,z) columns matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a (vertical) vector `A=[ x1; y1; z1; ...; xn; yn; zn ]` that comes from an operation on a cell array.

Operations on cell arrays doesn't allow me to keep the positions of the values within each cell even if they have the same size.

So how could I make the A vector looks like this again:
`B=[ x1, y1, z1; x2, y2, z2 ;...; xn, yn, zn]`.

I know I can tweak with loops but I'm sure there is an existing function or sequence of functions that would do the job. The `reshape` one doesn't give me good results.

Comment: In your specific case, `B = reshape(A,3,[]).'`.

Comment: I don't think you have experimented enough with **reshape**. Try more with transpose of argument and result itself.

Comment: @s.k unfortunately the question has been closed by an admin so I can't answer to tell you *why* you're not getting the results you expect (which was the implied second question, and is not answered in the 'duplicate' article either). The reason is that matlab works down *columns*. So if you have a vector of length nm, when you're reshaping it into a matrix of size [n,m] it will place the first n elements of the vector in the first *column*, then the next n elements go into the second column, etc etc, until all nm elements have been inserted. Now study the above solution to see why it works.